# Is it acceptable to paint weathering steel?

Tags: materials, steel, structural-engineering

Weathering steel is not typically painted, because it produces a thin rust layer that protects the rest of the steel from further corrosion. Would painting weathering steel be an acceptable additional line of protection, or would this cause some unforeseen complication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Maintenance Coatings of Weathering Steel](http://ntl.bts.gov/lib/32000/32400/32427/FHWA-RD-92-055.pdf) , published in 1995 by the US Department of Transportation

From page 11 of the report:

> Painting
>   of
>   new
>   uncontaminated
>   weathering
>   steel
>   is
>   generally
>   not
>   considered
>   a
>   problem.
>   Test
>   fence
>   and
>   laboratory
>   data
>   developed
>   by
>   the
>   paint
>   industry
>   have
>   indicated
>   that
>   conventional
>   coating
>   systems
>   such
>   as
>   oil
>   alkyds
>   and
>   epoxies
>   will
>   perform
>   comparably
>   on
>   weathering
>   steel
>   and
>   on
>   carbon
>   steel
>   if
>   the
>   degree
>   of
>   surface
>   preparation
>   is
>   equivalent.
>
> The
>   major
>   problem
>   faced
>   by
>   highway
>   departments
>   and
>   other
>   owners
>   of
>   weathering
>   steel
>   structures
>   is
>   protecting
>   weathering
>   steel
>   that
>   has
>   corroded
>   in
>   the
>   presence
>   of
>   chlorides
>   and
>   other
>   contaminants.
>   Conventional
>   cleaning
>   techniques
>   such
>   as
>   dry
>   abrasive
>   blasting
>   do
>   not
>   remove
>   the
>   chlorides,
>   which
>   apparently
>   penetrate
>   the
>   bases
>   of
>   pits
>   in
>   the
>   steel.
>   The
>   performance
>   of
>   standard
>   highway
>   coatings
>   such
>   as
>   oil
>   alkyd,
>   epoxies,
>   and
>   zinc-rich
>   systems
>   over
>   chloride
>   contaminated
>   steel
>   has
>   not
>   been
>   satisfactory.

Additionally, the [Florida Dept of Transport](http://www.dot.state.fl.us/officeofdesign/CPR/WeatheringSteelBridges.shtm) is recommending using:

> weathering steel for new steel bridges in suitable environments.  Use a single coat of inorganic zinc paint system for extremely aggressive environments.  Where higher aesthetics are required, use a 3 coat inorganic zinc paint system with clear coat finish.  The use of the 3 coat system with clear coat finish should be an exception